# Java - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems

Tags: java, mysql, database, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I have some problem in my JDBC code. I am trying to connect through MySQL but it gives me an error. My error log is given below if you have some time.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    BLOB cannot be resolved to a type
    BLOB cannot be resolved to a type

    at serialize.SerializeDeserialze.main(SerializeDeserialze.java:73)
```

My code is given below. I am using `mysql-connector-java-5.1.20.jar` driver:

```
package serialize;
/*
 By vivek
*/

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import oracle.sql.BLOB;

/****
CREATE TABLE java_objects (object_id NUMBER, object_name varchar(128), object_value BLOB DEFAULT empty_blob(), primary key (object_id));
SQL> desc java_objects;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 OBJECT_ID                                 NOT NULL NUMBER
 OBJECT_NAME                                        VARCHAR2(128)
 OBJECT_VALUE                                       BLOB

SQL> select SEQUENCE_NAME, MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE, INCREMENT_BY, LAST_NUMBER from  user_sequences;

SEQUENCE_NAME                   MIN_VALUE  MAX_VALUE INCREMENT_BY LAST_NUMBER
------------------------------ ---------- ---------- ------------ -----------
ID_SEQ                                  1 1.0000E+27            1          21
JAVA_OBJECT_SEQUENCE                    1 1.0000E+27            1           1

*/
public class SerializeDeserialze {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String WRITE_OBJECT_SQL = "BEGIN "
        + "  INSERT INTO java_objects(object_id, object_name, object_value) "
        + "  VALUES (?, ?, empty_blob()) " + "  RETURN object_value INTO ?; " + "END;";
    String READ_OBJECT_SQL = "SELECT object_value FROM java_objects WHERE object_id = ?";

    Connection conn = getOracleConnection();
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    list.add("This is a short string.");
    list.add(new Integer(1234));
    list.add(new java.util.Date());

    // write object to Oracle
    long id = 0001;
    String className = list.getClass().getName();
    CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall(WRITE_OBJECT_SQL);

    cstmt.setLong(1, id);
    cstmt.setString(2, className);

    cstmt.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.BLOB);

    cstmt.executeUpdate();
    BLOB blob = (BLOB) cstmt.getBlob(3);
    OutputStream os = blob.getBinaryOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oop = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
    oop.writeObject(list);
    oop.flush();
    oop.close();
    os.close();

    // Read object from oracle
    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(READ_OBJECT_SQL);
    pstmt.setLong(1, id);
    ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    rs.next();
    InputStream is = rs.getBlob(1).getBinaryStream();
    ObjectInputStream oip = new ObjectInputStream(is);
    Object object = oip.readObject();
    className = object.getClass().getName();
    oip.close();
    is.close();
    rs.close();
    pstmt.close();
    conn.commit();

    // de-serialize list a java object from a given objectID
    List listFromDatabase = (List) object;
    System.out.println("[After De-Serialization] list=" + listFromDatabase);
    conn.close();
  }

  private static Connection getHSQLConnection() throws Exception {
    Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
    System.out.println("Driver Loaded.");
    String url = "jdbc:hsqldb:data/tutorial";
    return DriverManager.getConnection(url, "sa", "");
  }

  public static Connection getMySqlConnection() throws Exception {
    String driver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/demo2s";
    String username = "oost";
    String password = "oost";

    Class.forName(driver);
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    return conn;
  }

  public static Connection getOracleConnection() throws Exception {
    String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:databaseName";
    String username = "userName";
    String password = "password";

    Class.forName(driver); // load Oracle driver
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    return conn;
  }
```

Comment: do you have oracle jar on your classpath?

Comment: No i only put mysql jar in my classpath .....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error happens when you use Eclipse as IDE and try to run code that doesn't even compile. Check your *Problems* view in Eclipse, and fix the compilation errors before executing the application.

Comment: Thanks, this was it. This happened to me when I added an import statement before the package statement.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a MySQL driver, but your class uses an Oracle BLOB class. Either use the Oracle JDBC driver, or use a different class for BLOB.

Since your code mentions HSQL, MySQL and Oracle, you will probably want to get rid of the Oracle-specific BLOB implementation.