# Unresolved compilation exception is giving when debugging junit test cases

Tags: java, junit4

I'm trying to debug unit tests in eclipse IDE, There is no any issue in addPlatform() method in line `292`. but when I'm debugging the test case, it gives following error without hitting first line of `addPlatform()` method. `PSMDataManager.class` file is created and its in right location

Please give me a suggestion to avoid this exception.

```
public static boolean addPlatform(String platformName, String accountId, String accountDn) {
    try {
        ManagePSMData bean = getPSMDataStoreBean();
        boolean success = false;
        success = bean.addPlatform(platformName, accountId, accountDn);
        return success;
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        log.info("Error while adding an Platform " + platformName
                + " platform already exists");
        return false;
    }
}
```

java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

```
at com.bc.myview.psm.util.PSMDataManager.addPlatform(PSMDataManager.java:292)
at com.bc.myview.psm.controller.ManagePlatformSelectController.addPlatform(ManagePlatformSelectController.java:178)
at com.bc.myview.psm.controller.ManagePlatformOverviewControllerTest.addPlatform(ManagePlatformOverviewControllerTest.java:69)
at com.bc.myview.psm.controller.ManagePlatformOverviewControllerTest.setUp(ManagePlatformOverviewControllerTest.java:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runBefores(SpringMethodRoadie.java:273)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie$RunBeforesThenTestThenAfters.run(SpringMethodRoadie.java:332)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runWithRepetitions(SpringMethodRoadie.java:217)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runTest(SpringMethodRoadie.java:197)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.run(SpringMethodRoadie.java:143)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:142)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:61)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:54)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:52)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: paste some code here.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224201/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-error-unresolved-compilation-problems?rq=1 and dozens of other "eclipse + unresolved compilation" questions. The answer is to check the Eclipse output window where there will be a lot of messages mentioning the the code does not even compile.