# Cannot add -ea arguments to Eclipse class

Tags: java, eclipse

Here's a simple program that I try to run:

```
public class TutorialExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean example = true;
        assert example == true;
    }

}
```

I have tried to follow [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5509180/3251199) exactly for this common issue, but am unsuccessful. I still get the resulting error that reads:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
  assert cannot be resolved to a type
  Duplicate local variable example
  Syntax error on token "==", = expected
```

Here is a sample image of my run configurations with the VM argument `-ea` included.

[image]

Comment: See [Exception in thread “main” java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224201/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-error-unresolved-compilation-problems).

Answer (score 1):

The Run Configuration only sets options for when you run your code. You have a problem with compiling the code.

Open the Preferences and go to the 'Java > Compiler' page. Check that the 'Compiler compliance level' is set the same level as the Java release you are running (but must be at least 1.4 for `assert`).

It is also possible to have Java settings specific to a project so also check the project 'Java Compiler' page in the Properties for the the project.